# Fastlane error while publishing app to testFlight using adHhoc

Tags: ios, terminal, code-signing, testflight, fastlane

I am working on CI/CD by using `Fastlane` automation server. I have configured Fastlane on my machine.

Now, I am trying to publish my app on TestFlight using AdHoc Distribution certificate. When I run the below command in terminal:

```
fastlane ios beta
```

It fails to **Export** with **Exit status: 70** and the error it gives is

> Provisioning profile "myAdHoc_test" is not an "iOS App Store" profile.

Also somewhere in the logs, it prints

```
▸ Archive Succeeded
[13:50:59]: Generated plist file with the following values:
[13:50:59]: ▸ -----------------------------------------
[13:50:59]: ▸ {
[13:50:59]: ▸   "provisioningProfiles": {
[13:50:59]: ▸     "com.testApp": "myAdHoc_test"
[13:50:59]: ▸   },
[13:50:59]: ▸   "method": "app-store",
[13:50:59]: ▸   "signingStyle": "manual"
[13:50:59]: ▸ }
```

I am wondering isn't it possible to launch build on testFlight using AdHoc certificate. Because almost all the time we use AdHoc certificate for TestFlight builds.

If anyone ever encountered the same error, please let me know how you resolved this. Or suggest me If I am doing something wrong.

Here is the content from my FastFile:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do    
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    build_app(scheme: "testApp")
    gym(
    scheme: "testApp",
    export_options: {
    provisioningProfiles: {
      "com.testApp": "myAdHoc_test"
    }
  }
    )
    upload_to_testflight
  end
end
```

Comment: can you try using distribution certificate?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am already using AdHoc distribution certificate.

Comment: you have latest profile?

Comment: you need Appstore distribution.

Comment: isn't it possible to upload testFlight build with AdHoc certificate using Fastlane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my mistake.. I messed up things..

In my FastFile, I am using "beta" action which means uploading to appstore for Beta Review and obviously we need app store distribution certificate for that.

But I was using adHoc instead.

Resolved this by using"pilot" action in FastFile.